# Infinite loop after reading a file using fscanf

Tags: c, file

I am using fscanf to read the input

> (2,3)
>
> (3,4)

from a file but it goes into an infinite loop whenever I run the program. The input is from a file say abc.txt which must be passed as a command line argument. The code is give below

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv){

    int a,b;
    FILE *fp=fopen(argv[1],"r");

    while(!feof(fp)){
        fscanf(fp,"(%d,%d)",&a,&b);
        printf("\nThe values are :%d %d\n",a,b);
    }
    
    fclose(fp);

}
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: not match scan pattern.

Comment: `while(!feof(fp))` has never worked and never will in C. The EOF is never known in advance, only *after* an I/O operation.

Comment: [More detail about `while (!feof(fp))` here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong).

Answer (score 1):

When `fscanf` does not find the data that looks like what you would like to read, it does not advance the reading position, so EOF never gets reached. Check that the `fscanf` gives you two numbers back, and break when it does not:

```
while(!feof(fp)){
    if (fscanf(fp,"(%d,%d)",&a,&b) != 2) {
        break;
    }
    printf("\nThe values are :%d %d\n",a,b);
}
```

You can drop the `feof` check altogether, because the `break` is going to happen sooner.

Comment: The feof in the while hurts my eyes... while it sort of works, it does so for all the wrong reasons.

Comment: @Jens Right, I wanted to fix the OP's code just to make it work, and left a hint on how to "beautify" it. This way it would "stick" in his mind better.

Answer (score 1):

> Notice that stream's internal position indicator may point to the
>   end-of-file for the next operation, but still, the end-of-file
>   indicator may not be set until an operation attempts to read at that
>   point.

```
while(fscanf(fp,"(%d,%d)\n",&a,&b) == 2){
    printf("\nThe values are :%d %d\n",a,b);
}
```

Will do the trick.

Comment: @P0W, I know, fgets and sscanf is a best choice, but OP is asking for the problem

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv){
    int a,b;
    FILE *fp=fopen(argv[1],"r");
    char linebuff[32];

    while(fgets(linebuff, sizeof(linebuff), fp)){
        sscanf(linebuff,"(%d,%d)",&a,&b);
        printf("\nThe values are :%d %d\n",a,b);
    }

    fclose(fp);

}
```

Comment: You should the check th return from sscanf, otherwise undefined behavior may occur in the printf.

Comment: sure, it had better do so Well is good. I expect implicitly that it is the correct format(I'm following the original on this matter).

Comment: It blur the problem rather than that there is no need.

Answer (score 1):

I think all you need is `'\n'`

This works for me with your code, on a sample input as yours.

```
 fscanf(fp,"(%d,%d)\n",&a,&b);
                    ^
```

But try using `sscanf` & `fgets` for such operations.